# Arrays with Elements Forming a Sequence in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm writing a MATLAB script and I have a situation where I need to create an array of a particular size, in which the elements form a well-defined sequence.

Doing this with a loop is quite easy, like saying a(n) = 2*n + 5 for every index inside a loop. But it's a strange language and have commands that do some array operations directly. I was wondering if there is a shortcut version of this with a single command or so.

Comment: It's not _strange_, it's [_vectorized_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your desired sequence is `a(n) = 2*n + 5`, you might do this in a loop with

```
N = 10; % number of elements in the output array
a = NaN(1,N);
for n = 1:N
    a(n) = 2*n + 5;
end
```

You can condense this into a single array operation. In this simple case you can use the same multiplication operator `*` but generally it's a good habit to use the [element-wise operator](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html) `.*` so you can compute between elements of multiple arrays.

```
N = 10;  % number of elements in the output array
n = 1:N; % define input array (same as array previously looped over)
a = 2.*n + 5;
```

Or in a single line

```
a = 2.*(1:10) + 5
```